# ExtJS4: Find tree node by screen coordinate or HTML element

Tags: extjs, treeview, extjs4, mouseevent, coordinates

In my web application I work with ExtJS4 and I use an Ext.tree.Panel. For a custom drag and drop implementation I need to find the tree node by its screen coordinates.

Is there a way to find a tree node by its screen coordinate? Or is it possible to find it via its HTML element?

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be not very efficient to seek node by coordinates as the only way to find the node by coordinates is to walk over all nodes.

Finding node by HTML element seems like more logical approach to me. Extjs4 tree utilizes the `view`. So you can try the [view.getRecord](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.view.View-method-getRecord) method:

```js
var node = tree.view.getRecord(htmlEl);
```

I haven't tried this code but it should work provided you passed correct `htmlEl`.

Answer (score 1):

One part of your question has already been answered.

If you *really* need to get HTML element (use it only as last resort) by screen coordinates, then you will need [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint).

Extra info and quirks here: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/06/more_ie9_goodne.html